# C++ Understanding boost asio multicast receiver

Tags: network-interface, netstat, udp, multicast, boost

I have recently started trying to learn the boost multicast receiver example and what it is doing [[code]](https://github.com/darwin/boost/blob/master/libs/asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp). I understand basic multicast receivers/sends but I have been struggling to understand a few things:

1. Within the code they have a listener address and a multicast address. Is the multicast address the address on the local machine that the packet is being sent to, while the listener address is the address of the machine?
2. Followup to the first question - In the default code they have the listener address as 0.0.0.0 . In older network code I never explicitly came into contact with this. What is the purpose of the listen address and is there any good reference for what its uses are?
3. When I set the listener address to 0.0.0.0 and my multicast address to 224.0.0.10 and run a netstat I cannot find the multicast address. I would expect to see the address that I am listening on unless I am not understanding something correctly.

Comment: a vast subject. I'd start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast#Overview . Also usually 0.0.0.0 means "any", like any ip belonging to me etc.

Comment: I think some of my main concerns currently are regarding the specific questions that I asked. In particular about why the address I registered to is not showing up. But I will definitely review that material in my free time. Thanks!